# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a combobox for the requisition numbers. on selecting an requisition number from combobox we should get the costcenter who has applied for that particular requisition. this is the code:

```
        cmd.Connection = con;
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        txtcc.Text = "";
        if (cmbreqno.SelectedValue != null || Convert.ToString(cmbreqno.SelectedValue) != "")
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_displaycostcenter";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@req_no", cmbreqno.SelectedValue);

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            adp.Fill(dsreqno,"selectedpurchase");
            if (dsreqno.Tables["selectedpurchase"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txtcc.Text = dsreqno.Tables["selectedpurchase"].Rows[0]["req_no"].ToString();
            }
            dsreqno.Tables["selectedpurchase"].Clear();

        }
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        //rdr.Close();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: In your code the line is obviously commented off: //rdr.Close();

Comment: it doesn make any diff. i tried using that line.still the same error.

Comment: Why are you trying to recreate the same connection in the first line of your second 'if' statement?

Comment: Why do you need that rdr variable (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();) if you are not using it?

Comment: can yoy please edit my code and tell me what exactly you are saying. i m still trying to figure out.

Comment: @JuStDaN asked a reasonable question; it seems like your code snippet contains plenty of redundant statements, that should be cleaned up.

Comment: @Kaushik27 - If you can't figure out your code, I'm not sure we can either.  As others have pointed out, it's a tad bit confusing.  For example, you're using a `SqlDataReader` that you don't do anything with once you execute the `SqlCommand`, and then you're using what appears to be a `SqlDataAdapter` (`adp`) that you are working with...but there's no information as to what `adp` actually is...

Comment: The code you posted isn't inside a loop by any chance, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    txtcc.Text = "";
    if (cmbreqno.SelectedValue != null || Convert.ToString(cmbreqno.SelectedValue) != "")
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_displaycostcenter";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@req_no", cmbreqno.SelectedValue);

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.Read())
        {
         txtcc.Text= rdr[0].ToString();//assuming sp_displaycostcenter returns costcenter.
        }
        rdr.Close();

    }        
    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard code block from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) to read data as shown below, and replace variables with your own ones:

```
private static DataSet SelectRows(DataSet dataset,
                                  string connectionString,
                                  string queryString) 
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand( queryString, connection);
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        return dataset;
    }
}
```